# DateInput in django admin form

Tags: python, django

I'm editing the form of my app admin section.

**model.py**

```
class Friend(models.Model):
id         = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
genre      = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(("M", "Male"), ("F", "Famale")))
birth_date = models.DateField()
```

**admin.py**

```
class FriendAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  change_form_template = 'admin/change_form.html'
  change_list_template = 'admin/change_list.html'

admin.site.register(Friend, FriendAdmin)
```

**form.py**

```
class FriendForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form    = Friend
  fields  = ('birth_date',)
  widgets = {'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}
```

I expect that my form contains only the "birth_date" field and that it has the   "form-control" class and the "DateInput" type. Nevertheless, my form contains all the fields and the "birth_date" is a simple text field. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.
I've imported bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker, jquery and moment library and I've added this code to my **change_form.html** page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Where does change_form.html resides ?

Comment: @scharette In "app\templates\admin" i've overwrite all template file

Answer (score 0):

Add class datepicker to your attributes

```
class FriendForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form    = Friend
  fields  = ('birth_date',)
  widgets = {'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control datepicker'})}
```

Comment: Done, but my input has only the "vDateField" class